# WordPress Multisite Redirect Loop After Botched Plugin Update

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, google-compute-engine, bitnami

So I've seen a bunch of questions like this, but many of them have no answers or the setup seems to be slightly different, so I thought I'd venture a new one.

I also apologize if some of this is vague and rushed, I'm sort of pulling my hair out trying to figure things out, but want to give as much detail as possible.

So I have a multisite WordPress installation on a Google Compute Engine instance. It was launched from the Cloud Launcher (https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/bitnami-launchpad/wordpress-multisite). I have three sites running, one at mydomain.com, one at dev.mydomain.com, and one at staging.mydomain.com. It's all been working great for the past several months, but this morning a colleague was updating a plugin (Beaver Builder in case that turns out to be significant), and perhaps simultaneously taking a backup with Updraft Plus. In the middle of the update/backup, the browser redirected to a long error saying the update failed, and from then on the site was showing a 500 Server Error.

I got in to work about half an hour later and noticed it was showing the "Apache2 Debian Default Page". I took a look at the httpd.conf, and noticed the DocumentRoot was pointing to the default Apache folder. I tried changing it to the WordPress install folder, and then was getting a different error related to permissions. I set the file permissions of the wordpress install to the recommended settings, and after that both subdomains worked. The root URL was kind of working -- it redirected from mydomain.com to http://IPADDRESS/wp-signup.php. I looked in the wp-config and saw that DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE was now set to the IP address, as well as the home and site url fields in the database. I changed them all to the domain name, and started getting a redirect loop error.

So for now I've left it as redirecting to the IP address, and added a NOBLOGREDIRECT setting to the wp-config to stop the wp-signup.php redirect. I am obviously not great at sys admin things, so I have no idea what to try next. I've ruled out the htaccess, plugins, and DNS settings (DNS hasn't changed).

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you got the Debian Apache page then it is highly likely that someone installed the Debian apache2 package, which conflicts with the apache bundled in the stack. I advise you to uninstall the Debian Apache:

```
  sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

Then restart the server services:

```
  sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```